# How do I drag and drop with in one table in UI5?

Tags: sapui5

I noticed on the documentation you can drag and drop between two tables https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Table/sample/sap.m.sample.TableDnD.
But is there a way to drag and drop on the one table (same table). I have written the code for drag and drop but the drag and drop event isn't triggered when I try to drop in the same table.

```
<mvc:View controllerName="ariba.cso.kaarecommendation.controller.Recommendation" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:f="sap.f" xmlns:dnd="sap.ui.core.dnd">
    <f:DynamicPage id="dynamicPageId">
        <f:title>
            <f:DynamicPageTitle>
                <f:heading>
                    <Title text="{i18n>appSubTitle}"/>
                </f:heading>
                <f:actions>
                    <Button text="{i18n>presentation}" press="onPress"></Button>
                    <Link id="linkid" visible="false" text="{i18n>download}" href="{/powerpoint}" press="linkPress"/>
                </f:actions>
            </f:DynamicPageTitle>
        </f:title>
        <f:content>
            <Table id="tableid" items="{private}" width="auto" mode="MultiSelect">
                <columns>
                    <Column demandPopin="false" width="auto" hAlign="Begin">
                        <Text text="{i18n>recommendation}"/>
                    </Column>
                    <Column minScreenWidth="Small" demandPopin="true" popinDisplay="Inline" hAlign="Begin">
                        <Text text="{i18n>itemid}"/>
                    </Column>
                    <Column minScreenWidth="Small" demandPopin="true" popinDisplay="Inline" hAlign="Begin">
                        <Text text="{i18n>areas}"/>
                    </Column>
                    <Column minScreenWidth="Small" demandPopin="true" popinDisplay="Inline" hAlign="Begin">
                        <Text text="{i18n>regions}"/>
                    </Column>
                    <Column minScreenWidth="Small" demandPopin="true" popinDisplay="Inline" hAlign="Begin">
                        <Text text="{i18n>url}"/>
                    </Column>
                </columns>
                <dragDropConfig>
                    <dnd:DragInfo groupName="itemsgroup" sourceAggregation="items"/>
                    <dnd:DropInfo groupName="dragdrop" drop="onDragDrop"/>
                </dragDropConfig>
                <items>
                    <ColumnListItem>
                        <cells>
                            <Text text="{private}"/>
                            <Text text="{private}"/>
                            <Text text="{private}"/>
                            <Text text="{private}"/>
                            <Link href="{private}" text="{i18n>urltext}"/>
                        </cells>
                    </ColumnListItem>
                </items>
            </Table>
        </f:content>
    </f:DynamicPage>
</mvc:View>

onDragDrop: function () {
            var oSwap = this.byId("tableid").getSelectedItems()
            if (oSwap.length !== 2) {
                var bCompact = !!this.getView().$().closest(".sapUiSizeCompact").length;
                MessageBox.error(
                    "Please pick two items.", {
                        styleClass: bCompact ? "sapUiSizeCompact" : ""
                    }
                );
            }
            else{
                var jObject = JSON.parse(this.getModel("table").getJSON());
                var first = JObject.indexOf()
                var second = JObject.indexOf()
                jObject[first] = 
                jObject[second] = 
                this.setModel(new JSONModel(jObject), "table");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<dnd:DragInfo sourceAggregation="items"/>
<dnd:DropInfo drop="onDragDrop" targetAggregation="items" dropPosition="Between" dropLayout="Vertical"/>
```

You can refer to [this](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.f.GridContainer/sample/sap.f.sample.GridContainerDragAndDropFromList) example in the SDK for further info